# Custom block on product page if product is out of stock / in stock

Tags: magento1.9.3, out-of-stock, product-page, custom-block

I want to add two **custom blocks** on **product page** - one to be displayed if product is in stock and the other one if product is **out of stock**.

Answer (score 0):

on `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/YourTheme/catalog/product/view.phtml`

file add below code

```
if($_product->isInStock()){
     echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); 
}else{
     echo  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); 
}
```

Comment: @Anna if my answer is solved your requirement then mark as accepted, so other user who has same problem can take benefit from this answer